# Please Help! Someone sent me Polygon USDC to my ETH address on Gnosis. I have redeployed the same address and need to move funds out

Tags: wallets, gnosis-safe, gnosis

someone has sent me Polygon USDC onto the ETH Gnosis Safe address of my wallet (eth:0xf60B82309D90c0c90826266aaa22b00322C2f632). This is the transaction onto the same address on Polygon: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x297de4ac22ca162b77980f4402a21db29437724e6e9376b77b562029780ee9e3

I have followed the steps from Mikhail's video and I think I have correctly redeployed the same address
https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741 - loom video
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x90f0994a5031872b47e27707d7420a029da8a6c115213d2dc899cd40c0add3db - transaction to create the same address on Polygon

If this is all done correctly I would like to move out the USDC from that Polygon address onto a different wallet so then we can move back to a gnosis-safe UI friendly Polygon wallet.

To complicate things a bit more when I checked the new Polygon wallet's owners are the first 3 addresses that were used when the eth multisig was set-up. Only 1 of these addreses is still an owner but I can easily get in touch with the others and ask them to help with moving funds out.

Can someone please help me what should I exactly do now to move the funds out? I am not technical at all so a step by step or Loom video would be the most helpful. Please help a fren out here.

Comment: What do you mean? It was created on the same address as the eth gnosis but on polygon

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I was looking at a different transaction. Unfortunately, if you didn't change the original owners you'll their approval to retrieve the USDC.

Comment: Hey Ismael! I am in touch with the original owners I just don't know what is the step by step process to actually move the funds out. I am not technical. Can you help me do this?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't used gnosis as a wallet.